# How can I disable verbose on parse server?

Tags: parse-server

I managed to enable VERBOSE on my parse server during development.
Now that I want to switch to production, I can't find any way to disable it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
var api = new ParseServer({
 databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
 cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
 verbose: false,
 ...
```

in your index.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use following commonds to enable and disable the Verbose

```
 // enable 
    heroku env vars are set like: heroku config:set VERBOSE=1

// disable 
    Unset it later with: heroku config:unset VERBOSE
```

you can check for [more details](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1135)

Answer (score 0):

//add env variable in our own server or Heroku dashboard

```
VERBOSE = 1 or 0 //enable or diable
```

in index.js

```
let VERBOSE = process.env.VERBOSE;
if(VERBOSE == 1)
{
    VERBOSE = true;
}else{
    VERBOSE = false;
}
let parseServer = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: .....,
verbose:VERBOSE
});
```

Done